# Imagegrid in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm following an example from the matplotlib documentation on [Imagegrid](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html), and I'm trying to replicate it from within Jupyter notebook:

```
% matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np

im = np.arange(100)
im.shape = 10, 10

fig = plt.figure(1, (4., 4.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,  # similar to subplot(111)
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 2),  # creates 2x2 grid of axes
                 axes_pad=0.1,  # pad between axes in inch.
                 )

for i in range(4):
    grid[i].imshow(im)  # The AxesGrid object work as a list of axes.


plt.show()
```

Expected output:

[image]

What I'm getting:

[image]

I'm not getting the grid of images, as you can see. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
If I remove the `%matplotlib inline` option, I just get this (it's `cell[1]` to prove I restarted my kernel):

[image]

No plots shown.

I'm running `matplotlib` version `3.0.0`, checked with `conda list matplotlib`, `jupyter` is `4.4.0`, checked with `jupyter --version`. On Windows 10, Anaconda, python 3.6.

Comment: You might need to make the `%matplotlib inline` *after* your import statements?

Comment: @MichaelHall nope, tried that after restarting my kernel. still doesnt work, unfortunately.

Comment: try fig.show() for kicks

Comment: what are your versions of mpl and jupyter? I would update to latest and try again. Mine just works.

Comment: @ak_slick I get this error `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py:448: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  % get_backend())` and then only 1 image shows up as before.

Comment: try restarting your kernel and running %matplotlib or %matplotlib inline in the first cell by itself. Then try the plot in the second cell. It appears this was/is a bug in jupyter. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6675

Comment: @ak_slick mpl is 3.0.0 with `conda list matplotlib`, jupyter is 4.4.0 with `jupyter --version`. And unfortunately, I (1) restarted kernel, (2) ran %matplotlib in the first cell, (using Qt5Agg backend) (3) the rest of the code in the second cell and it's still 1 image only. Ditto with `%matplotlib inline`. Thanks for your help, maybe I will cross-post it to matplotlib github and check with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [issue with matplotlib 3.0.0](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12370). This has now [been fixed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12363), such that it will not occur in the upcoming 3.0.1 bugfix release.

In the meantime you have two options.

1. Revert to matplotlib 2.2.3
2. Decide to not crop the images when using `%matplotlib inline`. Do so via

   ```
   %config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}
   ```

   in IPython or Jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
%matplotlib inline
```

and restart everything or put it in a separate cell as seen below.  It appears that the magic command always needs to be run in a separate cell before the plotting and if it was run before the kernel needs to be restarted. See here
[enter link description here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6675)

[image]

and it will work.  %matplotlib inline is not necessary to render plots in jupyter it is just a convenience. plt.show() will render plots whenever it is called.

I have had this issue with some mpl in jupyter. I think the issue is that the magic command causes it to render any plot as soon as it is available as opposed to mpl which waits until it is told to render and how.

Full example code straight from the mpl example you linked in your question:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np

im = np.arange(100)
im.shape = 10, 10

fig = plt.figure(1, (4., 4.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,  # similar to subplot(111)
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 2),  # creates 2x2 grid of axes
                 axes_pad=0.1,  # pad between axes in inch.
                 )

for i in range(4):
    grid[i].imshow(im)  # The AxesGrid object work as a list of axes.

plt.show()  # Renders all available axes when called
```

[image]

Comment: if I don't specify `%matplotlib inline` then I just get `<Figure size 400x400 with 8 Axes>` as output. I don't get how did you get the plots to show without the `inline` option?

Comment: plt.show()   renders the plots available whenever it is called

Comment: I'm aware of what `plt.show()` does typically. I just never had the experience of having the plots appear inline in Jupyter without using the magic command. It still doesn't, as you can see in my edit.

Comment: Whether or not `plt.show()` shows the figure, depends on which backend has been set. It will require the webagg backend (aka `%matplotlib inline`) to show the figures inline. However, often distributions preconfigure this to be used upon jupyter startup, such that 60% of the people have the experience that they don't need to type `%matplotlib inline` anywhere.